# Extract words from string of specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

In a given string extract only alphanumeric apart from words between '::' irrespective of space between ':'and alphanumeric  it should be able to extract it . below is the sample of code

```
import re

message = "ass :gifs_e4VLc8f2_galabingo: ass dof:stickers_t3B0l2J7_galabingo:dor"
message1 = ":gifs_e4VLc8f2_galabingo::stickers_t3B0l2J7_galabingo:"
# Regex pattern to extract words that do not start and end with colons
pattern = r'(?<!:)(?::[^:]+:)*([^:]+)(?::[^:]+:)*(?!:)'

# Find all occurrences of words in the message that do not start and end with colons
words_without_colons = re.findall(pattern, message)
words_without_colons1 = re.findall(pattern, message1)
print(words_without_colons)
print(words_without_colons1 )
```

Actual output :

Op 1: ['ass ', 'ass dof', 'or']
op 2: ['ifs_e4VLc8f2_galabing', 'tickers_t3B0l2J7_galabing']

Expected output :
op1 :  ['ass ', 'ass dof', 'dor']

op2 : [] #empty list

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using re.split would make this easier by using a separator formed of uninterrupted characters between colons (with optional leading/trailing space):

```
import re

pattern  = r" ?:[^ :]*?: ?"

message  = "ass :gifs_e4VLc8f2_galabingo: ass dof:stickers_t3B0l2J7_galabingo:dor"
message1 = ":gifs_e4VLc8f2_galabingo::stickers_t3B0l2J7_galabingo:"

*words,  = filter(None,re.split(pattern,message))
*words1, = filter(None,re.split(pattern,message1))

print(words)  # ['ass', 'ass dof', 'dor']
print(words1) # []
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.. it helped me to fix the bug